# PHP Class child modifying parent

Tags: php, object

I have a class called `db` which is an accessor for various functions relating to my database, e.g. adding rows, validating input or generating html forms/tables.

I currently have to have `db_html`, `db_valid` etc. classes which extend this `db` class. This means if I'm doing more than one type of operation in a single route I have multiple objects. It also means I need to write code which targets:

```
$db_html=new db_html('table name');
$html=$db_html->make_table();
```

What I've seen done in other APIs is more the form:

```
$db=new db('table_name');
$html=$db->html->make_table();
```

Which would then also allow:

```
$db->access->insert([data]);
```

With a single object containing the database schema.

However as far as I can see, to create the above `html` and `access` components still requires me to create an extended class:

```
function __construct($name){
  $this->html=new db_html($name);
}
```

And any subsequent modification of the properties of one child will not be propagated to other children, as even though all are "children" of the class, they have no way of accessing properties of their "parent", which in this case is both a literal parent and a container.

There's also a chance I've wrapped myself up and become confused. What would be the best way to resolve this?

Comment: use instances as objects

Comment: If you use static variables in the parent class, any change to them in any of the classes will effect the other ones.

Comment: I'd like to know why someone thought this question merited a lack of research or effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reference a method of container object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240322/reference-a-method-of-container-object-in-php/1240420#1240420)

This question has been well answered by the accepted answer in the linked question.

> You have to modify your code to provide a relationship. in OOP-speak, we call this [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation).

See that question for a worked example. In my case I have solved as follows:

```
abstract class db_master {
protected $children=array();
protected $parent;

function __get($name){
    if (!isset($this->children[$name])){
        $this->add_child($name);
    }
    return $this->children[$name];
}

function link_parent(&$parent){
    $this->parent=$parent;
}

function add_child($name){
    $class='db_'.$name;
    $child=new $class();
    $child->link_parent($this);
    $this->children[$name]=&$child;
}
}
```

Thus if I have this in my library:

```
class db extends db_master {
    function __construct($name){
    }
}
class db_html extends db_master {
    function generate(){
    }
}
```

I can do this in my code:

```
$db=new db($name);
$html=$db->html->generate();
```

And it will work, without having to declare the sub class or do the linking. The abstract class prevents someone else reusing the code from mistaking master for the parent class.